# function name as parameter in c++

Tags: c++, function

Let's say I have function:

```
double fun (int *a, int b)
{
//sth
}
```

and I had other function `fun2`, to which I'd want to pass the above function like this:

```
fun2(fun);
```

How to define `fun2` and how to use the function passed as paramter inside it?

Comment: Do you know how to declare function pointers? If so, then what exactly is your question. If not, then you should see your C++ textbook for a full explanation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So to do so I need to use function pointers?

Comment: You have no choice but to use function pointers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Well there are two other choices below.

Comment: ok guys I figured it out myself, thank you for answers though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old-fashioned way (a function pointer):

```
void fun2(double (*fun)(int*, int));
```

The C++11 and onwards way:

```
#include <functional>
void fun2(std::function<double(int*, int)> fun);
```

Comment: maybe I am wrong on that, but I use `std::function` only when I need potentially different kinds of callables, whenever I need only one particular kind of callable I stay away from `std::function`, in this case I would prefer the function pointer, or make `fun2` a template

Comment: @idclev463035818  like `std::function` due to its type safety. It would be nice if it could model default arguments, but that's a language issue I think.

Answer (score 3):

Well the easiest way is to use template (which will deduce the type for you, without digging in function pointer and company):

```
template<class Funct>
double fun2(Funct my_funct){
    my_funct( /*parameters of the function, or at least something that can be casted to the required types of the function parameters*/ );
}
```

In poor word, you "pass" a function pointer, which can be used as a function, and so using `operator()` you invoke it.

This will compile with everything that has an `operator()(/*parameters of my_funct*/)` defined and so objects with that operator defined (for example, check `functors`) or callable like functions and lambdas.

Comment: You miss conversion, ... I would drop compile conditions.

Comment: Better words: Functor, callable.

Comment: @Jarod42 you mean the conversion between function pointer and function? (and so that we don't need to dereferenciate it)?

Comment: Although I quite like this alternative in some situations, I'm not sure it's the easiest way. Personally I find function pointers the easiest way, but then I did start out as a woolly C programmer.

Comment: I meant `[](char c){} (int(42))`. no `operator ()(int)`, but it even compile.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes absolutely, it's cleaner, but maybe for someone that has no notion of function pointer, functional and so on, it's "easier" tu understand... but it's a personal opinion

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, you are right, i've edited the answer, maybe now it's more "formally" correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular old function pointer for this. You can alias it to make it look a little nicer as a function argument.

```
using callback = double( * )( int* a, int b );

void fun2( callback cb )
{
    // Invoke directly.
    auto ret{ cb( nullptr, 0 ) }; 

    // Or with 'invoke'.
    ret{ std::invoke( cb, nullptr, 0 ) };
}
```

Calling `fun2`:

```
fun2( [ ]( auto ptr, auto value ) { return 1.0; } );
```